# LSI versus keyword stuffing

Tags: seo

I'm trying to get a better handle on good SEO.  After reading a few articles on LSI, it seems like LSI would encourage keyword stuffing.  While maybe not using the same keyword exactly, but using lots of synonyms.  I.e., if LSI is about creating a matrix of overlapping titles and words, wouldn't that by the very process point to high keyword density?   Sorry, I'm sure it's more complex than this, but if LSI is important, I need to better understand it.  Thanks.

Comment: I think writing useful, relevant content is more important than worrying about LSI - relevant keywords are naturally a part of that. This is a useful read: https://www.searchenginejournal.com/latent-semantic-indexing-wont-help-seo/240705/

Also see section 3 here for a very straightforward explanation: https://backlinko.com/seo-copywriting

Just make sure your content reads naturally - reading it aloud may help.

Comment: Alex, thank you.  There just seems to be so much BS out there regarding SEO. It's hard to know what is true and what is just more hype.  I had just seen LSI thrown around here enough that I thought I should at least research it more as I trust what I see here more than all of the SEO driven blogs and websites.  Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah - it's too easy for anyone to publish anything, and you don't know who to trust without some knowledge of your own. If it helps, some favourite (definitely trustworthy, in my opinion) SEOs and websites are Brian Dean (content & links), Marie Haynes (Google penalties, content quality & more), Jon Cooper (links), Moz (everything), Cyrus Shepherd, Annie Cushing, Rand Fishkin, and Varvy (speed). Google produce (mostly) excellent advice. If all that seems overwhelming, my simplest advice is to make user-friendly websites - whether that's buying a product, finding advice or something else.

Comment: Thank you Alex.  I appreciate the additional information and resources.